# How to prove Python is safe

Tags: python, security, open-source

Our corporate IT people are paranoid. This is normal, but they are requiring me to prove that Python doesn't have any malicious (or insecure) code in it (of course, this includes all the modules I have loaded).  From the Department of Defense:

"Security Vulnerability Management -- There are a variety of reasons that organizations want to know what components their developers are using, but security is certainly a biggie.  Arguably open source is at least as secure as proprietary code, but at the same time, for even very popular components there are hundreds of known vulnerabilities in the National Vulnerabilities Database.  And new ones are being discovered every day, so it's critical that organizations not only have processes for vetting incoming components, but also monitor used components going forward to ensure they know if new problems arise."

Any ideas how I would go about the Python body of code?  In an ongoing fashion?  I'm pretty much done with my project and am not inclined to rewrite it in C#.  Thanks.

Comment: How have they proved that C# is safe?

Comment: "they are requiring me to prove that Python doesn't have any malicious (or insecure) code in it" - of course it has insecure code in it. So does the OS, the web browser, C#, important firmware and drivers, the networking equipement, etc. The hardware is insecure (see Spectre/Meltdown for high-profile examples). The people are definitely insecure. Everything is insecure. Unless we get way better at computer security in the future, it's all going to be a matter of risk management.

Comment: I believe Ada is certified "safe" by a variety of different regulatory agencies (but only certain implementations), but almost no other modern-ish language is. Getting Python certified in the same way would presumably require a multi-million-dollar, multi-year auditing process, and lots of clout within the government and/or even more millions of lobbying.

Comment: they should be more worried about their developers programming securely in the language they choose rather than the security aspects of the language.

Comment: It may be very tempting to close the question as too broad or primarily opinion-based, **but** I believe it provides us with a one-time opportunity to address this really practical issue. I vote to keep it open, perhaps even _protected_.

Comment: Not going to comment about the security or insecurity of python, but this is something that should be addressed and dealt with before you start on a project, especially if security is a concern.

Answer (score 7):

also from the DOD

http://dodcio.defense.gov/Open-Source-Software-FAQ/#Q:_Is_there_an_.22approved.22.2C_.22recommended.22_or_.22Generally_Recognized_as_Safe.2FMature.22_list_of_Open_Source_Software.3F_What_programs_are_already_in_widespread_use.3F

> *Commercial software (including OSS) that has widespread use often has lower risk, since there are often good reasons for its widespread use.
>   The MITRE study did identify some of many OSS programs that the DoD is
>   already using, and may prove helpful. Examples of OSS that are in
>   widespread use include:*
>
> ```
> Apache - Web server
> Mozilla Firefox - Web browser
> Mozilla Thunderbird, Evolution - Email client
> OpenOffice.org - Office document suite
> OpenSSH - Secure Shell
> OpenSSL - SSL/cryptographic library implementation
> bind - DNS server
> Postfix, Sendmail - Mail servers
> gcc - Compiler suite
> GNAT - Ada compiler suite (technically this is part of gcc)
> **perl, Python, PHP - Scripting languages**
> ```

in otherwords if its good enough for the DOD surely it is good enough for whatever super secret stuff your company is working on...

(also note that this makes no mention of Pip package XYZ that you installed ... thats gonna be harder to prove ....)